# Python parsing date and find the correct locale_setting

Tags: python, datetime, internationalization, locale, datetime-parsing

I have the following date string: '3 févr. 2015 14:26:00 CET'

```
datetime.datetime.strptime('03 févr. 2015 14:26:00', '%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S')
```

Parsing this failed with the error:

```
ValueError: time data '03 f\xc3\xa9vr. 2015 14:26:00' does not match format '%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S'
```

I tried to loop over all locales with `locale.locale_alias`:

```
for l in locale.locale_alias:
    try:
        locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, l)
        print l,datetime.datetime.strptime('03 févr. 2015 14:26:00', '%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S')
        break
    except Exception as e:
        print e
```

but I was not able to find the correct one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To parse localized date/time string using [ICU date/time format](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from datetime import datetime
import icu  # PyICU
import pytz # $ pip install pytz

tz = icu.ICUtzinfo.getDefault() # any ICU timezone will do here
df = icu.DateFormat.createDateTimeInstance(icu.DateFormat.MEDIUM,
                                           icu.DateFormat.MEDIUM,
                                           icu.Locale.getFrench())
df.setTimeZone(tz.timezone)

ts = df.parse(u'3 févr. 2015 14:26:00 CET') #NOTE: CET is ignored
naive_dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(ts, tz).replace(tzinfo=None)
dt = pytz.timezone('Europe/Paris').localize(naive_dt, is_dst=None)
print(dt) # -> 2015-02-03 14:26:00+01:00
```

`df.applyPattern()` could be used to set a different date/time pattern (`df.toPattern()`) or you could [use `icu.SimpleDateFormat` to get `df` from the format and the locale directly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29548727/4279).

It is necessary to use an explicit ICU timezone (so that `df.parse()` and `.fromtimestamp()` could use the same utc offset) because `icu` and `datetime` may use different timezone definitions.

`pytz` is used here, to get a proper UTC offset for past/future dates (some timezones may have different utc offsets in the past/future including reasons unrelated to DST transitions).

Comment: Martijn Pieters, J.F.Sebastian : Thanks a lot for your precious help.

Comment: Hi!
two questions
1)  how do I install it on Windows?
2) maybe it exists something new or better NOW?

Comment: @VasylKolomiets: no idea to both but my guess would be: 1- try `python -m pip install PyICU` and if it fails, google corresponding error 2- it might depending on your use-case/constraints.

Comment: @jfs  Here [link](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1412499/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b2-pandas-pyicu-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%80%d1%83%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8) I've asked it.

Answer (score 0):

Your format includes a *dot* for the abbreviation and uses 4 characters:

```
'03 févr. 2015 14:26:00'
#      ^^
```

but if I set the locale to `fr_FR` and format the same date:

```
>>> import locale, datetime
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, ('fr', 'UTF-8'))
'fr_FR.UTF-8'
>>> datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 3, 14, 26).strftime('%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S')
'03 f\xc3\xa9v 2015 14:26:00'
>>> print datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 3, 14, 26).strftime('%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S')
03 fév 2015 14:26:00
```

You'll notice only *3 characters* are used and no dot is included. Parsing the date only supports the same 3 character abbreviations:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('03 fév 2015 14:26:00', '%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S')
datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 3, 14, 26)
```

You could try the [`parsedatetime` library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/parsedatetime/) instead, others have [had success parsing French dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26294333/parse-french-date-in-python) with that tool.

Comment: Java Friends are laughing, as it works fine for them with following code :   `DateFormatSymbols dfs = new DateFormatSymbols(Locale.FRENCH);
   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yy", dfs);
   Date date = sdf.parse("09 févr. 08");
   System.out.println("--> " + date);`

Comment: Sure, but this is a different language, and `datetime` parsing is moving along but a little slowly. I'm sure the Python project would love to receive additional help fixing those issues.

Comment: @seb835: you could use PyICU if you like (the same backend that is probably used by Java). `parsedatetime` can also use it

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: good point; I missed that `parsedatetime` can make use of PiICU if installed.