# Python strptime finnish

Tags: python, datetime, localization, finnish

I have a Finnish representation of a date (*tiistaina, 27. lokakuuta 2015*) that I need to convert to a datetime object. However, the day and month names are not recognised by the datetime library in Python

I would expect something like the following to work:

```
import locale
from datetime import datetime

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'fi_FI')
the_date = datetime.strptime('tiistaina, 27. lokakuuta 2015', '%A, %d. %B %Y')
```

However, this results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/_strptime.py", line 500, in _strptime_datetime
tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/_strptime.py", line 337, in _strptime
(data_string, format))
ValueError: time data 'tiistaina, 27. lokakuuta 2015' does not match format '%A, %d. %B %Y'
```

I think this is because Python is expecting the day to be tiistai instead of tiistai**na** and the month to be lokakuu instead of lokakuu**na**

http://people.uta.fi/~km56049/finnish/timexp.html seems to suggest that there are, depending on the context, different ways to represent a day or month in the Finnish language.

How can I the string `tiistaina, 27. lokakuuta 2015` to a datetime object?

Answer (score 2):

`'%A, %d. %B %Y'` produces a different time string on my system too:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import locale
from datetime import datetime

#NOTE: locale name is platform-dependent
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'fi_FI.UTF-8') 
print(datetime(2015, 10, 27).strftime('%A, %d. %B %Y'))
# -> tiistai, 27. lokakuu 2015
```

---

You could use [`PyICU`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyICU) to parse a localized date/time string in a [given format](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from datetime import datetime
import icu # PyICU

tz = icu.ICUtzinfo.getDefault() # any ICU timezone will do here
df = icu.SimpleDateFormat('EEEE, dd. MMMM yyyy', icu.Locale('fi_FI'))
df.setTimeZone(tz.timezone)

ts = df.parse(u'tiistaina, 27. lokakuuta 2015')
print(datetime.fromtimestamp(ts, tz).date())
# -> 2015-10-27
```

Related: [Python parsing date and find the correct locale_setting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28429512/4279)

It works but PyICU is a big dependency and you have to read C++ docs for most things.

---

There is [`dateparser` module](https://dateparser.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) that should work if you [add Finnish data to a simple yaml config -- similar to how it is done for other languages](https://github.com/scrapinghub/dateparser/blob/69baab722a887cee0268136ce03dee5d6dda175d/data/languages.yaml#L1057). Here's a working example for Dutch language:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import dateparser # $ pip install dateparser

print(dateparser.parse(u'dinsdag, 27. oktober 2015',
                       date_formats=['%A, %d. %B %Y'],
                       languages=['nl']).date())
# -> 2015-10-27
```

Related: [Parse French date in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26294333/4279)

Answer (score 2):

The days of week and month names are substituted in nominative case for `%A` and `%B` respectively; however that date format has DOW in the essive case, and the month in partitive. Declension in Finnish is quite complicated in general case, but for this case, you can suffix a DOW name with `na` to get the required essive, and `ta` to the month to get the partitive.

Thus the `strptime` format `'%Ana, %d. %Bta %Y'` with the `fi_FI` locale is guaranteed to work for all your dates:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('tiistaina, 27. lokakuuta 2015', '%Ana, %d. %Bta %Y')
datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 27, 0, 0)
```