# Convert Spanish date in string format?

Tags: python, string, date, localization

How would I convert a date in string format to compare it with the current time?

I tried this:

```
import time, datetime

if time.strptime(date.find(text=True), "%a, %d/%m/%Y").now() > datetime.now():
```

But I get this error:

```
ValueError: time data u'Dom, 07/02/2016' does not match format '%a, %d/%m/%Y'
```

Need advice on how to do this.

Comment: Did you set the correct locale? What does `locale.getlocale(locale.LC_TIME)` return?

Comment: name 'locale' is not defined ...

Comment: It works if "Dom" is replaced by "Sun" so I also assume it is a locale issue.

Comment: `import locale` should solve that. [`locale`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html) is a standard module that deals with --well-- the locale, i.e. encodings, currency and date/time formats. You are probably parsing your date in `'C'` locale, which has no notion of Spanish(?) `'Dom'`. You need  to setup the proper locale when parsing localized date/time.

Comment: related: [Python strptime finnish](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33375709/4279)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to setup the proper locale before handling language/region specific data.

Try again with

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, '')
time.strptime(date_string, "%a, %d/%m/%Y")
```

The `''` tells the library to pickup the current locale of your system (if one is set).

If you need to parse the date in a different locale, the situation is a little bit more complex. See [How do I strftime a date object in a different locale?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18593661/how-do-i-strftime-a-date-object-in-a-different-locale) for the gritty details.

It is possible to explicitly set a specific locale, e.g.

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'es_ES.UTF-8')
time.strptime('Dom, 01/02/1903', '%a, %d/%m/%Y')
=> time.struct_time(tm_year=1903, tm_mon=2, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=6, tm_yday=32, tm_isdst=-1)
```

but remember, that this setting is global. `strptime()` does not accept a parameter to specify a particular locale to parse with, it always picks up the global locale.

If the date is user-supplied, I have used [`dateparser`](https://dateparser.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) package as a welcome alternative. Especially so, since its `parse()` function accepts an explicit [`languages`](https://dateparser.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#dateparser.parse) parameter.

Comment: `dateparser` works like a charm. Thanks!