# python 3 datetime.strptime doesn't work with German format

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, date-format, strptime

Need to change a string in German into a date. I try to use the following code:

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime_object = datetime.strptime('24. Juli 2017', '%d %B %Y')
print(datetime.strftime(datetime_object, '%d.%m.%Y'))
```

this code fails with the next error:

```
ValueError: time data '24. Juli 2017' does not match format '%d %B %Y'
```

However it works correct with English text:

```
datetime_object = datetime.strptime('24 July 2017', '%d %B %Y')
print(datetime.strftime(datetime_object, '%d.%m.%Y'))
```

Output:

```
24.07.2017
```

Comment: This question may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28429512/python-parsing-date-and-find-the-correct-locale-setting. On sumarry you first have to cahnge the locale to Germany and then it will parse months in german

Comment: I found simple way, using "dateparser" lib.
`import dateparser
print(dateparser.parse('24. Juli 2017').strftime('%d.%m.%Y'))`
works perfect

Answer (score 3):

You have to fix the format (forget the dot after day) and have to set locale to 'de_DE'.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> import locale
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, "de_DE") # german
'de_DE'
>>> datetime.strptime('24. Juli 2017', '%d. %B %Y')
datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 24, 0, 0)
```